# base operand of -> has no pointer of has non-pointer type ’

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a map "languages" and an iterator to that map "it".

```
map < string, pair< pair<string,string>, pair<int,int> > > languages;
map < string, pair< pair<string,string>, pair<int,int> > >::iterator it;
```

I'm trying to find the pair of int to a certain element, suppose c is a string already there in the keys of my map.

Using         `languages.find(c)->second->second->first;` I expect to get the right iterator pointing to the right element of map although I'm stuck with an error while compiling has non-pointer type `std::pair<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >, std::pair<int, int> >`

How to fix this? Any help would be appreciated, any help with explanation would be VERY much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `languages.find(c)` returns an iterator (and you *do* know that element exists? Dereferencing the `end` iterator is UB) and therefore have an overloaded `->` operator, the `second` member of the pair is in turn a pair and not an iterator which means you need to use the `.`:

```
languages.find(c)->second.second.first
```

Comment: Many thanks sir, I didn't pay attention for such huge detail. Pathetic why some people down vote us when we need an explanation for small details like these.